# How to merge content of 2 list of strings in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

Let's say I have

```
var list1 = new List<string>();
var list2 = new List<string>();
```

I'd like to merge content of both list. Is looping over one of the list to extract and add content to the second list the only way to merge content?

```
foreach(var name in list2)
{
   list1.add(name);
}
```

Is there a different way of merging content?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `AddRange`.
This example will take the items in `list2` and add them to `list1`

```
list1.AddRange(list2);
```

Comment: @Gabe, Is that's gonna work on IEnumerable as well? Because instead of a list, I might have to work with IEnumerable.

Comment: `AddRange` specifies `IEnumerable<T>` as a parameter (right side). Note that `AddRange` is only defined for `List<T>` (so left side must be a list).

Answer (score 1):

[`System.Collections.Generic.List.AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) will modify an existing list by adding the contents of another.

[`System.Linq.Enumerable.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) will return a sequence containing the items from the first list followed by the items from the second list, while leaving both original lists unchanged.

[`System.Linq.Enumerable.Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) will return a sequence containing all the unique items from both lists, leaving the originals unchanged.